# java html5 websocket server and client example?

Tags: java, javascript, html, websocket, push

Hi all the stackoverflow people
i need an websocket server and client implementation example in jAVA,
i researched and not found tangible result,
please help me 
thank you

Comment: Try google.com next time ;-)

Comment: You really need to demonstrate that you have done some work at least.  Did some google searches, read some documents, played with some test code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163592/standalone-websocket-server-without-jee-application-server/53208425#53208425

Answer (score 7):

- [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)
- [jWebSocket](http://jwebsocket.org/)

First two results on a google search for [java websocket](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+websocket). How did you not find these?

Comment: I recommend the first one, at least for people which want to see something running quickly. jWebSocket server has tons of dependencies and configuration files, a lot of plugins enabled by default and you don't know what's really necessary. And after you set up everything and you get like 200 lines of debug output in the console you don't know what's about, it doesn't work. With Java-Websocket I was able to run a working example from own java file in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). A lot of samples and works with all existing framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple Java I/O websocket server that supports the full message length and multiple connections check this out http://code.google.com/p/jfraggws/